# Configure spring bean to be abstract or not in xml configuration through propeties

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, javabeans

I'm using Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE version and have following configuration:

```
<bean id="advice.audit" class="com.mysite.SuperClass" abstract="${myproperty.from.file}"/>
```

I'm getting:

`${myproperty.from.file}' is not a valid value for 'boolean'`

How can I achieve this behavior or maybe someone will provide a better idea of controlling bean creation from properties.

Upgrading to Spring 3.1 is not an option, so Spring Profiles could not be used.

Comment: Can you show where is myproperty.from.file defined? Are you sure it is in contex?

Comment: Property is defined in properties file which is correctly configured and loaded by Spring.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how it would make sense to have a bean be abstract or not based on a property in the first place. Are you just trying to conditionally include the bean based on a properties file, basically like Spring Profiles would give you? Can you use the property to determine which of two files to include, one of which has the bean and the other of which does not? Or have your bean have a property of "enabled" or not, and just have the bean always there but not always doing anything.

Comment: Property resolving is done when the bean is initialized. This requires the properties to be available. Personally, I ran into problems when implementing BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor. Then the bean was initialized before the properties are read, an i got a similar error.

Comment: Peter Cooper Jr., I'm trying conditionally include or not include bean like Spring profiles will do. I do not have two options for bean. I only want to include or not. Bean is third-party lib and have no property "enabled".

Comment: Post your full stack trace.

Comment: Does the description of a way to do Spring 3.0 environment configurations at http://www.drillio.com/en/software-development/spring/context-bootstrapping-with-different-environment-configurations/ help?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `abstract` attribute is not meant to be replaced at run time with a property value. The `abstract` indicates if a `<bean>` declaration should be used as a template. For example, you could have this

```
<bean abstract="true">
    <property name="someField" value="some value" />
</bean>
```

If the value of `abstract` was somehow, at runtime, set to `false`, Spring would try to create a bean for a `<bean>` declaration without a `class` attribute. What would it create?

Note also that in the `beans` XSD, the `abstract` attribute is of type `xsd:boolean`

```
<xsd:attribute name="abstract" type="xsd:boolean">
    <xsd:annotation>-<xsd:documentation>
        <![CDATA[ Is this bean "abstract", that is, not meant to be instantiated itself but rather just serving as parent for concrete child bean definitions? The default is "false". Specify "true" to tell the bean factory to not try to instantiate that particular bean in any case. Note: This attribute will not be inherited by child bean definitions. Hence, it needs to be specified per abstract bean definition. ]]>
    </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation></xsd:attribute>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not desired behavior.

Comment: @tvelykyy I don't know how you are getting around the XML parser, but your `ApplicationContext` instance should fail right away trying to parse the `xml` context file.